# predicateWithFormat:argumentArray: Using all items in NSArray

Tags: core-data, nsarray, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest, predicatewithformat

```
- (void)filterViaCategories:(NSArray *)array   {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(todo_category_id == %@)" argumentArray:array]; 
}
```

but when I have used:

```
po predicate
```

Result is:

```
todo_category_id == 41123..
```

It just using **41123** from zero index element of array

i want all categories from data base for all id present in array not the only object at index zero:
`(todo_category_id == 41123, 41234, 33455)` etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Then you should not be using `predicateWithFormat:argumentArray:` and you need to change your format.

You want something like:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todo_category_id IN %@", array];
```

Comment: but i causes me an error like:
[__NSCFNumber countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: my array has NSNumber elements inside..can i change them to string values of "ids".?

Comment: `todo_category_id` is a string attribute? But the array contains only numbers?

Comment: Then it looks like you didn't actually send an array to the method, you just sent an individual `NSNumber` instance...

Comment: I have checked inside array..it has count of 3 and values thats i have printed at its index are 1254,8765,9853

Comment: What is the stack trace then as you are definitely using a number when the code expects an array.

Comment: How can i find stack trace?

Comment: Add an all exception breakpoint in Xcode so the debug session stops when any exception is found

Comment: debugger stops at main.m and causing this error inside console
[__NSCFNumber countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000a0a33

Comment: Did you add the breakpoint? Try pressing continue to get a stack trace in the console. Or look at the left of the screen for a stack trace.